# How to reload a page in jquerymobile?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

In My Project I am having some javascript to implement my work, but it is not taking when I am starting the page,but it is working after reloading the page.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
require_once"session.php";
$slat =$_GET['slat'];
$slang =$_GET['slang'];
$elat =$_GET['elat'];
$elang =$_GET['elang'];
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <?php require_once"header.php";?>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Near My Location Contacts</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   /* function refreshPage() {
        alert('dfg');
    window.location.href,
    {
      allowSamePageTransition : true,
      transition              : 'none',
      showLoadMsg             : false,
      reloadPage              : true
    }
}
refreshPage();*/
    //<![CDATA[
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
//var haight = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157);
//var oceanBeach = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7683909618184, -122.51089453697205);
var haight = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $slat;?>,<?php echo $slang;?>);
var oceanBeach = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $elat;?>,<?php echo $elang;?>);
function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: haight
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
}

function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
    origin:haight,
    destination:oceanBeach,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize();calcRoute()"> 
  <div data-role=page id=nmContacts >
    <div data-role=header data-theme="e" >
        <a href="geoMapGrid.php" data-icon="back" ><font size="2px">Back</font></a>
        <h1 align="left"><font size="2px">Near My Contacts</font></h1>
    </div>
  <div data-role=content style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <div data-role=content id="map_canvas" style="width:95%; height:300px"></div>
<div id="directionsPanel" style="width:97%;height 100%"></div>

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

In the above I am having body onload it is not working at the first time after refreshing only it is working.

Comment: This mixing of PHP, Javascript and HTML into a single file is very disorganized and can lead to a lot of trouble down the line.  You really should try to separate them out.  Also, you're injecting PHP variables directly into your generated javascript without any kind of validation or escaping.  This can only lead to huge security issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
      Before You are calling to this page You have to specify in href like the following
```

assume that you are having the following link to load:

```
<a href="sample.php" rel="external">sample</a>
```

here `href="external" You have to specify otherwise it wont work.....